# How to pass an optional parameter for font-family and font-weight

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a method which takes font-family and font-weight as optional parameters.

```
private void txtBlockSettings(int _FontSize, 
                              FontFamily _FontFamily = new FontFamily("Consolas"), 
                              FontWeight _FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal)
{
    //Some stuff here
}
```

But when I try to create above method I get an error :

```
1. Default parameter value for _FontFamily must be a compile time constant.
2. Default parameter value for _FontWeight must be a compile time constant.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default value of an optional parameter of a method must be one of the following types of expressions:

-a constant expression;

-an expression of the form new ValType(), where ValType is a value type, such as an enum or a struct;

-an expression of the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value type.

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

The type of a constant declaration specifies the type of the members that the declaration introduces. The initializer of a constant local or a constant field must be a constant expression that can be implicitly converted to the target type.

**A constant expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile time**.

Therefore, the only possible values for constants of `reference types` are `string` and `null`.

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx)

However, you can achieve this by declaring overloads as follows:

```
private void txtBlockSettings(int _FontSize,FontFamily _FontFamily,FontWeight _FontWeight)
        {
            //Some stuff here
        }

        private void txtBlockSettings(int FontSize, FontWeight fontWeight )
        {
          txtBlockSettings(FontSize,new FontFamily("Consolas"), fontWeight);   
        }

        private void txtBlockSettings(int FontSize, FontFamily family)
        {
            txtBlockSettings(FontSize, family, FontWeights.Normal);
        }

        private void txtBlockSettings(int FontSize)
        {
            txtBlockSettings(FontSize, new FontFamily("Consolas"), FontWeights.Normal);   
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message told you, and the current parameters you defined as default parameter are created at runtime not a compile time constant, CMIIW. You can make the method like following instead:

```
private void txtBlockSettings(int _FontSize, 
                              FontFamily _FontFamily = null, 
                              FontWeight? _FontWeight = null)
{
    if(_FontFamily == null) _FontFamily = new FontFamily("Consolas");
    if(_FontWeight == null) _FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
    //Some stuff here
}
```

Comment: I like this. And (I realize this is old, but) to take it a step further you can now use the [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) to do this: `_FontFamily = _FontFamily ?? new FontFamily("Consolas");`

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that because all reference type parameters can be initialized with null constant only. And 'FontFamily' is reference type.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to fix this. One possible way is to have two methods with the same name but different number of arguments:

```
private void txtBlockSettings(int _FontSize)
{
    txtBlockSettings(_FontSize, new FontFamily("Consolas"), FontWeights.Normal);
}

private void txtBlockSettings(int _FontSize, 
                              FontFamily _FontFamily, 
                              FontWeight _FontWeight)
{
    //Some stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as the compiler said, the default value params must be constant values, so you can get it by overloading the function.
code as this:

```
private void txtBlockSettings(int _FontSize)
    {
        //set the default params
        FontFamily _FontFamily = new FontFamily("Consolas");
        FontWeight _FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        //invoke the function using full params
        txtBlockSettings(_FontSize, _FontFamily, _FontWeight);
    }

    private void txtBlockSettings(int _FontSize,
                          FontFamily _FontFamily,
                          FontWeight _FontWeight)
    {
        //Some stuff here
    }
```